# jQuery selecting deep non id element

Tags: jquery

How i can select this deep non id element in jQuery ? And I do not want select first or last, just exactly by order (etc 3,4 "menu_transition" element in order ).

```
 <ul id="menu_container_content">
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <div class="menu_background"></div>
                    <div class="menu_transition"></div> 
                    <div class="menu_tile"><h2>ABOUT ME</h2></div>
                    <div class="menu_description">
                        <div>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In lectus enim, pharetra in gravida quis, vehicula id ante. 
                            Cras mollis, mauris sed fermentum tempus
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="menu_delimiter"></li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <div class="menu_background"></div>
                    <div class="menu_transition"></div> <!-- THIS CONCRETE ELEMENT I WANT EDITED -->
                    <div class="menu_tile"><h2>PROGRAMING</h2></div>
                    <div class="menu_description">
                        <div>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In lectus enim, pharetra in gravida quis, vehicula id ante. 
                            Cras mollis, mauris sed fermentum tempus
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
$('#menu_container_content .menu_item:eq(1) .menu_transition')
```

The [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selects the *n*<sup>th</sup> matching element (zero-based).

Answer (score 3):

Without using the `eq` selector, but using the `eq()` method instead:

```
$('#menu_container .menu_item').eq(n).children('.menu_transition')
```

which should avoid the need to concatenate together a string selector with "n" in the middle of it.